# How do I prevent postfix from recieving mail?

Tags: postfix

I only use my server to send out mail as I use Zoho for receiving email at my domain. I want to disable postfix from receiving any mail as spammers always try to send me mail or use me as a relay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a firewall rule blocking port 25.

You can also bind Postfix only to the loopback interface in your `main.conf` with

```
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
```

(http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#inet_interfaces)

I would consider it good practice to do both, that way you don't end up being a spam source if for some reason, one of the two methods gets turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Either block port 25 on your firewall or following this guide for a send-only postfix configuration:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers to prevent link-rot. Instead, add the most important points from the link to your answer.